# Find depth of tree in MongoDB documents using 'spring data mongo'

Tags: mongodb, tree, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

We have the documents in the following structure. I am trying to write a service using "spring-data-mongo" to traverse the documents and print a report as shown below (in output).

```
db.getCollection("tree").find({})

// Result
{
  "_id"  : ObjectId("5467cswrtr")
  "name" : "energy1",
  "rootId" : "10",
  "parent_id" : null,
  "id" : "10"
},
{
  "_id"  : ObjectId("5467cswrt54r")
  "name" : "energy2",
  "rootId" : "10",
  "parent_id" : 10,
  "id" : "20"
},
{
  "_id"  : ObjectId("54cswrtr")
  "name" : "energy3",
  "rootId" : "10",
  "parent_id" : "20",
  "id" : "30"
},
{
  "_id"  : ObjectId("54cswrtr")
  "name" : "energy4",
  "rootId" : "10",
  "parent_id" : "20",
  "id" : "40"
}
```

We can visualize the above document in tree form as below. We may have many such trees.

Tree Structure:

[image]

We are using Mongo version 3.2.12. I need to print the following report by traversing the documents using spring data mongo:

```
Name          rootId  Depth
============================
energy1        10       3
Agriculture    99       36

-- and so on
```

PS: I searched on Google and found out about `$graphlookup`, but it does not seem to be supported in mongo version 3.2.12.

Please help.